# Python groupby Timestamp along with mean and sum of other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the below df :

```
    DATETIME        OPEN    HIGH    Count 
02/03/1997 09:04:00 3046.00 3048.50  20        
02/03/1997 09:05:00 3047.00 3048.00  13        
02/03/1997 09:06:00 3047.50 3048.00  6        
02/03/1997 09:07:00 3047.50 3047.50  12        
02/03/1997 09:08:00 3048.00 3048.00  136          
02/03/1997 09:09:00 3048.00 3048.00  174          
02/03/1997 09:10:00 3046.50 3046.50  134          
02/03/1997 09:11:00 3045.50 3046.00  43           
02/03/1997 09:12:00 3045.00 3045.50  214          
02/03/1997 09:13:00 3045.50 3045.50  8            
02/03/1997 09:14:00 3045.50 3046.00  152
```

I want to `group` the dataframe by `5 Minute interval` along with `sum` of `Count` and `mean` of `OPEN and HIGH`.

I tried to do this for 1 min intevral using below code :

First I converted my DATETIME column to Day, hour, minute using below function :

```
def date_convertion(df):

    df['date_time_from_epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'], format='%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p', errors='coerce')
    df['date'] = df['date_time_from_epoch'].dt.date
    df['day'] = df['date_time_from_epoch'].dt.day
    df['month'] = df['date_time_from_epoch'].dt.month
    df['hours']= df["date_time_from_epoch"].dt.hour
    df['minute']= df["date_time_from_epoch"].dt.minute
    return df
```

and then used the below code to aggregate the date for each 1 Minute time interval :

```
d = {'Count':['sum'],'OPEN': ['mean'],'HIGH': ['mean']}
res = merged_data.groupby(['date','day','month','hours','minute']).agg(d).reset_index()
res.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in res.columns.values]
```

The above script work very well for `1 minute aggregate` data, but I want to do aggregation based on `5 minute` along with `Count(sum), OPEN(mean) and HIGH(mean)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
res = merged_data.resample('5Min', on='date_time_from_epoch').agg(d).reset_index()
```

Or [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
res = merged_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min', key='date_time_from_epoch')).agg(d).reset_index()
```